# SQL with order by and Top Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, distinct

```
SELECT distinct TOP 100 
event.[ExtId],
event.[EventId],
event.[StateId]
FROM
(
SELECT CS.[Id],
CS.[ExternalId],
CS.[EventId],
CS.[StateId]
FROM CS
ORDER BY CS.[Id] asc
) event
```

Is giving an error, in SQL saying Order BY Clause clause is invalid in views, etc... What is the best correct way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to order your subquery? I guess you want to order the outer query. Simply put the ORDER BY at the end.

Comment: @NunoMendes . . . Can you provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `GROUP BY`, because of the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 100 e.[ExtId], e.[EventId], e.[StateId]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CS.[Id], CS.[ExternalId], CS.[EventId], CS.[StateId]
      FROM CS
     ) e
GROUP BY e.[ExtId], e.[EventId], e.[StateId]
ORDER BY MIN(CS.[Id]);
```

I think this is entirely equivalent to:

```
SELECT TOP 100 CS.[ExternalId], CS.[EventId], CS.[StateId]
FROM CS
GROUP BY CS.[ExternalId], CS.[EventId], CS.[StateId]
ORDER BY MIN(CS.[Id]);
```

This is the more typical way to write the logic.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I want the distinct outside of the subquery